# Java regex confusion

Tags: java, regex, debugging

I hate ask stupid questions like this, but why doesn't my code do what I expect?

Java code in a main method:

```
String s = "\"The fat-dog [ruffus] @nd the stupid-cat [*mewzer*] don't like each other!\"";
String[] tokens = s.replaceAll("[\\x27]+", "").replaceAll("[^a-zA-z_\\x2D]+", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().split(" ");

System.out.println(s);
for (String t : tokens)
    System.out.println("Token: " + t);
```

This prints:

> "The fat-dog [ruffus] @nd the stupid-cat [*mewzer*] don't like each other!"
>
> ```
> Token: The
> Token: fat-dog
> Token: [ruffus]
> Token: nd
> Token: the
> Token: stupid-cat
> Token: [
> Token: mewzer
> Token: ]
> Token: dont
> Token: like
> Token: each
> Token: other
> ```

Which is mostly correct, except for those damn brackets!  Shouldn't they be replaced by the `"[^a-zA-z_\\x2D]+"` expression?  I even tried adding a `replaceAll("\\[\\]"," ")` and then a `replaceAll("\\x5B\\x5D"," ")` to no avail.

---

How can I get rid of these brackets?  What is keeping them from being replaced in the three replace all statements I just mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first try didn't work because of this

> replaceAll("[^a-zA-**z**_\x2D]+", " ")

That range of characters happens to actually include [ and ] in western european/north american sets.  [\]^`_ are placed between Z and a, which is normally a convenience when you write A-**z**, but also a pitfall for you!

You probably meant A-**Z**

Comment: Ahh, the subtle capitalization typo.  Sometimes you just need a second pair of regex comprehending eyes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
replaceAll("\\[\\]"," ")
```

Should probably be:

```
replaceAll("(\\[|\\])"," ")
```

You were trying to replace instances of `[]` with a , instead of replacing a `[` or a `]` with a .

Comment: Thanks.  That explains why the second two replaceAll expressions didn't work as expected, but what about the first?  `[` and `]` are not in the set `a-zA-z_\\x2D` correct?

Comment: [ and ] are in the set A-z, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a better way to do what you really seem to be wanting to do (removing all non-word characters from the string (except hyphen)):

```
String[] tokens = s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s-]+", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().split(" ");
```

This will leave digits in your string alone, though. Is that a problem?